# Why webmaster is showing error while I attempt fetch as Google?

Tags: hyperlink

I have been trying to solve this by myself but could not find any solution to this problem. Just recently I changed meta names for some of the pages and did fetch as google the homepage went well in the but it shows error with inner page. And why "Total robots.txt fetch errors" comes while my page https://www.paydaysunny.com/robots.txt is OK.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should Create a /robot.txt file with no content in it. Which will default to allow all for all type of Bots.

Comment: can you explain bit in detail? No content means? kindly share a url as an example. can I leave site without robots.txt